# Display a normal chart or D3Js in Node-red dashboard (over template ?)

Tags: node.js, charts, node-red

Has somebody already achieved to display a chart, not based on timeseries (like the chart from the dashboard), but on data passed to it?

I wonder if it is, perhaps, possible to use a template to do that? But I've no clue how to do it. If someone has a small example, it would be great.

Comment: This is way too broad a topic for SO, you will probably do better talking about it on the Node-RED mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution, using some code sample from the library... 
The link between msg.payload and data is still missing, but not far away

```
<style>

#chart svg {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}

</style>

<h3>test</h3>
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>



<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/master/build/nv.d3.js"></script>

<script>
    (function(scope) {
        console.log('Position 1');
        console.dir(scope);
        console.log(scope.msg);
        scope.$watch('msg.payload', function(data) {
            console.log('Position 2');
            console.dir(data);
        });
    })(scope);

function data() {
  var sin = [],
      cos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i/10)});
    cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i/10)});
  }

  return [
    {
      values: sin,
      key: 'normal',
      color: '#ff7f0e'
    },
    {
      values: cos,
      key: 'defect',
      color: '#2ca02c'
    }
  ];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    ;

  chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('frequence')
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))
    ;

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('amplitude')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
    ;

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data())
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
</script>
```